# Error "Unknown system variable 'lower_case_table_names'" when accessing MySql from Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I've got an SQL exception in eclipse while access to MySQL database. I connect to database but it gives an exception which is "lower_case_tables_names". I check mysql option and I change lower_case_tables_names option to 1 and 2 but still I couldn't solve the issue. What can i do?

```
try {
        System.out.println("DBMS connection established");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        connection = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test",
                "root", "");
        System.out.println("Database connection provided");

        stmt = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("You can execute sql comments");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown system variable 'lower_case_table_names' at
com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998) at   
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847) at 
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
```

Comment: What exception you got please add whole stack trace? What code you written to connect the DB? Or you are using some tool or eclipse feature to connect with DB

Comment: Can you post your exception?! How do you connect to your db?! Which version of MySql are you using?!

Comment: I am not sure what is your problem. You should be more specific. Add the OS you use and more details when the problem occurred. I had this problem once, and it was because I tried to import a database on Linux machine which previously was created on Windows machine. MySQL by default uses different case on these 2 Operating Systems. Here is an answer I found useful [link](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16198/mysql-case-sensitive-table-names-on-linux)

Comment: I use Windows 8.1 and eclipse luna, Mysql workbench 6.2 and mysql server 5.6. I can not add screen image because my post limit. Thanks for you for your helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using old methodology of setting variable in "my.cnf" file.

```
set-variable = lower_case_table_names=1
```

The above style is old for MySql server 5.6.
For this version, you must specify as (under the section [mysqld])

```
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Restart MySql and check.

If you still cant fix, Provide details of your "my.cnf" file.

Comment: I didnt even set the variables, but its not working for me. Everything is working fine for my another application. But for this its not working correct. I am trying to upload images to the mysql DB.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to change the version of `sql connector`.
I had also the same issue and I changed the `sql connector` from `5.1.38` to `5.1.21` and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue, changed the mysql connector version to 5.1.5 and its working perrfectly now.

Comment: how do you change it ?

Comment: @ChetanGowda you would be using a mysql connector jar to connect to the database right. You will have to download the mentioned version of that jar.